# PHP mySQL textarea --- the whole shibang

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, textarea

Long time reader, first time asker...I'll get to the point.

I'm passing textarea data to QUERY_STRING and need it to play nice with mySQL.  To be more specific, I need the text to show the correct line breaks and spacing while also displaying all characters (I'm looking at you, # and friends!).  ALSO, I need it to escape all the pesky ' and " characters.

I've tried (almost hopefully) everything.  I can't seem to get the ingredients right; I can get the spacing and line breaks to work but not the # characters.  I can get the # characters, but not the apostrophes.

ADD:  The reason I'm passing this data through the QUERY string and not, say GET, is because I'm using JavaScript (using XMLHttpRequest) to pass the data to a PHP file behind the scenes.

Specifically, the page is set up to send a message without refreshing the page (i.e. Facebook).  It takes the data from the ID textarea via DOM, passes it to a separate PHP file which handles the mySQL request but in the mix, I lose information and it doesn't translate.  I've been working on this for two days and can't get it to jive.  Help!

EDIT:
Here is the code.  Some of these code snippets are on different pages, but work together to attempt to send a message w/o updating/refreshing the page.

```
<textarea spellcheck='false' id='composeText' maxlength='250'>
</textarea>
<input type='button' value='Send' style='float:right;' onclick='sendMsg(<?php echo '123654674, 159753';?>)' id='sendMsg'>

parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$g);
if ($g) {
    $msg_id = $g['msg_id'];
    $msgFrom = $g['msgFrom'];
    $message = addslashes($g['message']);
    $message = nl2br($message);
    $msgTo = $g['msgTo'];
}

echo "<input type='hidden' id='msgToId2' value='".$msgTo."'>"; 


addMsg($msg_id, $msgFrom, $msgTo, $message, $conn);


function sendMsg(msg_id, msgFrom) {
    msg_id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1);
    msgFrom = '159753'; 

    msgTo = document.getElementById('msgToId').value;
    if (msgTo == "") msgTo = document.getElementById('msgToId2').value;
    message = document.getElementById('composeText').value; 
    message = message.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>');
    message = encodeURIComponent(message);

    getRequest(
           'sendMsg.php?msg_id=' + msg_id + '&msgFrom=' + msgFrom + '&msgTo=' + msgTo + '&message=' + message, // URL for the PHP file
           sendMsgOutput,  // handle successful request
           sendMsgError    // handle error
    );
    return false;
}


function addMsg($msg_id, $msgfrom, $msgto, $message, $conn) {

    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $message);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`msg_id`, `msgfrom`, `msgto`, `message`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$msg_id', '$msgfrom', '$msgto', '$message', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'))";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking in to [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)?

Comment: Definitely something I'll consider however I'd like to have something a lot simpler

Comment: It can be customized to remove all the extra tools. You can have it to have the normal formatting bits and bobs only.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely consider that if all of my options are maxed.  I'm hoping to do this with just PHP/JS if possible.  I'm sure I'm not the only person to try this......okay I can't figure out the italic thing...emphasize only pls ha

Comment: *TinyMCE is a platform independent web-based **JavaScript** HTML WYSIWYG
editor control released as open source under LGPL.*

Comment: You need to show your code so we can see what you're doing wrong. My guess is you're not calling `encodeURIComponent` when you put it into the query string. Or you're not using a prepared query or proper escaping when you create the MySQL query.

Comment: If the problem is with apostrophes, then the problem is that you're not escaping the data before substituting it into the query. But you really should be using prepared queries, to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: I added code..as you can see, I've tried a lot of things to make it work, and I feel like I've thrown so much at it, that I've made it worse.

Comment: Did you write `getRequest`? The PHP being mixed in with the JS makes this a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, I thought I'd leave this here, you could use something like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) which I've used, it is rather impressive.

**Usage**

A simple demo as per there site,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

*Overwhelmed by all the extra bits and pieces?*

Nothing to worry about as you can remove them and keep what you wish. Below is a minimal setup I use and it can be reduced further.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tiny-mce',
    toolbar: 'bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright bullist numlist outdent indent undo redo styleselect',
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false
});
```

The [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/) is concise too which is a plus point. From the [editors appearance](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/) to [content filtering](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/) it has a vast array of options which you can customize.

You can find the full feature list [here](https://www.tinymce.com/features/).

Comment: I tried the Tinymce, it's pretty cool but it does not solve my problem.

Step 1 - User clicks button to send msg
Step 2 - Process is pushed thru JS which gets the textarea data using DOM
Step 3 - JS pushes that data thru a background php page using XMLHttpRequest
Step 4 - Background php page takes that data and sends it to MySQL